# Две таблицы с выбором опций, между ними HTML

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Нужно просто сверстать две таблички.
В Таблице 1 будут находится какие-нибудь значения: к примеру Значение 1, Значение 2, Значение 3 и т.д.
Таблица 2 будет пустая.
Таблица будут находится на одной строке. Между ними будут 2 кнопки:
1) ">"
2) "<"
Соответственно, если в первой таблице выбрано значение и нажали ">", то значение должно перетекать во вторую таблицу.

Вопрос: как это лучше всего сделать?

Comment: javascript'ом вестимо.

Comment: @D.Mark прекрасно, а вы попытались как-то сами решить вашу задачу? Покажите код ваших попыток.

Comment: Это называется picklist. Можешь посмотреть плагин здесь https://github.com/Gabrielr47/pickList

Comment: Добавьте ваши попытки, ваш [mcve]. Посмотрите [ask]

Comment: @Kniham Больше спасибо! То что надо!

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказал @Kniham, элемент называется Picklist

Ссылка: https://github.com/Gabrielr47/pickList